# is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory with mybatis and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-aop, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Mybatis and trying to implement mybatis with Spring but getting the below runtime error while starting tomcat.

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and application context:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="uactivityDS"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
</bean>
```

The error is:

```
the resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory
```

The `mybatis-spring-1.0.0.jar` file exists in `war/web-inf/lib`, though.

Any idea what's going on in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [pom.xml](http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/sub-projects/mybatis-spring/tags/mybatis-spring-1.0.0/pom.xml) for mybatis-spring-1.0.0.jar, it has a compile time dependency of mybatis 3.0.4 which contains the class org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSessionFactory.

So include that jar as well along with others mentioned in the pom.xml and you should be good.

Comment: Got it resolved by adding <dependency> <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId> <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId> <version>3.0.4</version> </dependency> In pom.xml